# Excel - How to increment the count of cell in a column A (often with with blanks above) only when Column B cell = "A"

Tags: excel, countif

For context the numbers are samples taken, and the letters are the sub-samples within the larger sample.
Due to the nature of data-entry, column B is populated first (and easier) by hand and ranges from 1 to 6 sub-samples.

My data needs to look like below (importing new data into a legacy format)

Column A          Column B
001                 A
B
C
002                 A
B
003                 A
004                 A
B

How can I have column A autofill and increment by one only when column B cell is "A"?

something like =IF($B2="A",--increment from number above--,"")

I have browsed these and other forums and am still unsure how to use the increment number with COUNTIF as most answers seem to be for filling the BLANKS

Many Thanks

Comment: SOLVED this is what I needed. So simple. =IF(B2="A",MAX($A$1:A1)+1,"")

Comment: Post your answer in `Answer` area and accept to close it, so that it helps someone in the future.